# Wildfly VFS - URLClassLoader is not able to load properties file

Tags: java, wildfly, urlclassloader

We are facing weird issue on Wildfly(though it happens on Tomcat as well).
After new war deployment I am able to find resource bundle file, but after execution of some code(not sure what), wildfly is unable to load ResourceBundle file using URLClassLoader. Seems like ClassLoader issue but not sure.
How can we identify culprit of it?
Here is the code which is used to get ResourceBundle:

```
Locale locale = Locale.getDefault();
java.io.File fileObj = new java.io.File(bundleName);
java.net.URL resourceURL = null;

try {
    resourceURL = fileObj.getParentFile().toURI().toURL();
} catch (MalformedURLException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

URLClassLoader urlLoader = new URLClassLoader(
    new java.net.URL[] {
        resourceURL
});
java.util.ResourceBundle bundle = java.util.ResourceBundle.getBundle(
bundleName.substring(
bundleName.lastIndexOf(File.separator) + 1,
bundleName.lastIndexOf(".")), locale, urlLoader);
try {
    msg = bundle.getString(bundleMsg);
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
return msg;
```

Comment: Where are resource bundles located? As well as where is your code that does lookup located? what is deployment? war?

Comment: Resource bundles are part of war file, but not inside "WEB-INF". The code that does lookup is indside WEB-INF/classes folder.

Comment: Where in war file?

Comment: Here is the structure: - "query/resource_bundle" parallel to "WEB-INF"

Answer (score 0):

You cannot reference *any* object inside a WAR or JAR file through a `java.io.File` object. WARs and JARs do not contain "files".

Furthermore, if the structure is as you claim:

```
WAR
  WEB-INF
  query
      resource_bundle
```

then you cannot access it as class loader resource either.

You must use [javax.servlet.ServletContext.getResource(String path)](https://javaee.github.io/javaee-spec/javadocs/javax/servlet/ServletContext.html#getResource-java.lang.String-) or [javax.servlet.ServletContext.getResourceAsStream(String path)](https://javaee.github.io/javaee-spec/javadocs/javax/servlet/ServletContext.html#getResourceAsStream-java.lang.String-) to access resources in this location.

Only objects in the WEB-INF/classes directory are accessible through a class loader.

Given the nature of these resources, I think you probably really want them under WEB-INF/classes. How you do this depends upon how you build your web application. If you're using Maven then the correct source location would be `src/main/resources/query/resource_bundle`. Then you can just use:

```
 this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("/query/resource_bundle/" + bundleName);
```

if I've interpreted what you're trying to do correctly.